# Xcode Swift library Package.swift template

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I would like to locate Xcode's `Package.swift` Swift library (package) project template file.

I looked in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/MultiPlatform/Library/Library.xctemplate`, however, the only file I found was `TemplateInfo.plist`.

Where can I find it?

Comment: Could Xcode just be calling `swift package init`? Which of course just punts the problem to "where does the Swift command line tool get its package from?"

Answer (score 0):

As uliwitness said in the comments, Xcode probably just uses the `swift package init` command to generate a new project.

From the source code of [apple/swift-package-manager](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager), it looks like there is not a template *file* for Package.swift. Package.swift is generated by hard-coded string literals.

See the implementation for [`InitPackage.writeManifestFile`](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Sources/Workspace/InitPackage.swift#L137C18-L137C35). Here is an excerpt:

```
try writePackageFile(manifest) { stream in
    stream.send(
        """
        // The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

        import PackageDescription

        """
    )

    if packageType == .macro {
        stream.send(
          """
          import CompilerPluginSupport

          """
        )
    }

    stream.send(
        """

        let package = Package(

        """
    )

    var pkgParams = [String]()
    pkgParams.append("""
            name: "\(pkgname)"
        """)
```

One possible reason for not using a template file is that Apple wants SPM to be self-contained, and doesn't want to depend on an external template engine, such as Xcode's. Another reason might be that the logic for generating this file is rather complicated, and writing it with Swift is more readable than writing a template for it.